# How do I treat user input in textarea (in a HTML file) as python code?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, user-input

I'm trying to build a webpage with programming challenges. I used a  tag for the user input to type in the python code. How do I check whether the code inside is correct? Is there a way for me to execute the python code to see if it's correct?

Also, there are 2 types of programming challenges. The first one is based on the console output (i.e. print statements) and the second one is based on function output (i.e. return statements). How do I deal with both of these cases?

I have considered downloading the output into a python script and maybe running it from there, but I probably wouldn't be able to deal with the 2nd case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to view the correct code, you could first check if it matches your example code.

However, because of the nature of programming and that code can be made in different ways yet still have the same output, it would be essential to run the code.

In order for you to run the code, it would have to be run on the server side. If you don't know yet, in order to validate this Python code, you have to execute the code on the server.

The client could send the code to the server, evaluate it as Python code, then determine if it were correct.

In order to check if your return statements are correct, you may use test cases.

You would execute the Python function with the value you want to test. You could then compare the return result to determine wether or not the code is correct.